# Petrol extinction in Futurama

Tags: futurama

As I can recall from Futurama [season 06 episode 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Futurama_Holiday_Spectacular), In the robonica spirit, the female bots had to wrestle in petroleum oil which got extinct, leaving bender with only a can of it. Bender, along with crew, goes down the earth,digging, to get more petrol. The ship gets wrecked due to pressure and there, 500 million years later, the crew gets converted into petrol.

When he got back into Planet Express office (where the two female bots were fighting), he sees enough petroleum oil already there (which wasn't when he left 500 million years back) and quoted

> "There was enough petroleum for four and a half week, but it lasted for
>   500 million years. Its a miracle"

How did this petroleum arrived suddenly? If it was the same petrol which he used 500 million years back(amount to only few liters), how did it suddenly became a tub full of it? Also, isn't petrol a volatile liquid, which should've vanished into the air?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a '*Robanukah Miracle*'. This closely mirrors the "[miracle of the oil](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/five-myths-about-hanukkah/2015/12/02/2ea6fc3c-93ae-11e5-8aa0-5d0946560a97_story.html)" found in the Jewish Hanukah tradition, on which Robanukah seems to be largely modeled:

> After the Maccabees reclaimed the Temple, the story goes, **they found a
>   small amount of oil permissible for lighting the sacred sanctuary lamp
>   — enough for just one day. Miraculously, it lasted eight.** Jews thus
>   light candles on eight successive nights to recall this great miracle.

You may also want to take issue with the fact that Bender has evidently been active for 500 million years despite not having that much booze (with which to power himself) and the fact that we've seen in "The Late Philip J. Fry" that the Planet Express building doesn't survive even 50,000 years into the future, let alone 500 million years, all of which can be attributed to the fact that this was an "[elseworlds](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Elseworld)" episode.

Comment: correct. This is indeed the sarcasm